# Extract values only from a box not the pt

Tags: box

My codes are below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newbox\fightbox
\newcount\fightcount

\newcommand{\test}[1]{
\setbox\fightbox=\vbox{#1}%184.99pt
}

\begin{document}

\test{\includegraphics{./images/c02f001.pdf}}

\showthe\ht\fightbox

Running text

\end{document}
```

when I do compilation, LaTeX told the box value is `184.99954pt`, but I need to extract the value only, i.e. `184.9954` only, that `pt` is not required, is this possible?

Comment: You should use `\sbox\fightbox{#1}`. Can you please tell *why* you need the number?

Comment: @egreg can you share your mail id, so that I'll explain my requirement

Comment: @egreg actually I need to automate number of lines to be hang in wrapfigure, so the figure height can detect by auto without pt value, but it didn't accept the values in decimal format, please suggest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\strip@pt` to remove dimensions:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newbox\fightbox
\newcount\fightcount

\newcommand{\test}[1]{
\setbox\fightbox=\vbox{#1}%184.99pt
}

\begin{document}

\test{\includegraphics{example-image}}

\makeatletter
\strip@pt\ht\fightbox
\makeatother

Running text

\end{document}
```